# Is my ENT specialist ripping me off?

Tags: treatment, tinnitus

I have been to an ENT specialist regarding my tinnitus problem several times, but each time she just insists on doing a hearing test, which appears to be the standard one where you put on headphones to listen to a range of sounds in a soundproof room.

After the test, she will just quickly scan the results, tell me that the results are fine, there is no cure for tinnitus, and then give me generic advice like "try turning on the fan when you sleep to mask the noise". My actual consultation time (not counting the hearing test time) is probably 15 mins or less, and I am charged $200+ for this (which is the standard rate in Australia apparently).

I have no clue what this test is supposed to show in the first place (the specialist claims it can detect whether my ears are damaged, is this true?). Isn't there a more indepth test to find out what is causing the tinnitus exactly? I can't believe that I am being charged $200+ just to be told to "try turning on the fan". Is there anything i can do at all, or should i stop seeing doctors about it since "there is no cure"?

Can any medical professionals confirm if this is what a normal consultation with a specialist is supposed to look like?

Edit : Nobody has any clue?

Comment: Nobody has any clue?

Comment: I don't know what standard fees are in Australia, but I don't understand why you keep going for hearing tests to tell you what you already know. I would recommend seeking a second opinion.

Comment: @CareyGregory As i mentioned in the post, it was the doctor who insisted on a hearing test each time. Yes, i can get a second opinion, but what is the point if another doctor is just going to do the same thing? What i want to know is if this is what a typical consultation with a specialist supposed to be like? I am being given barely any information and generic advice that anyone can give.